# Using Masquerade to test UC coupons

Tags: 6, ubercart

I'm dealing with an old D6 Ubercart site that uses [UC Coupon](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_coupon) & [UC Free Order](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_free_order) to enable free orders for users with a certain role when they enter free order code. I'm masquerading as one these users but I'm finding it won't pick up on coupon code when I enter it. It gives me the "Warning: Coupon does not exist or is not valid." error.

I'm thinking it might be a quirk with how masquerade works. It looks like my account address book entries are showing up in Billing Information despite masquerading as another user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using masquerade, you could use `drush uli [%uid]`

It gives you a clean login to the site, which you could open in an incognito mode on a browser, removing all other cookies. This will allow you to debug without feeling that other modules are interrupting.

Bonus: add `--uri=[%site-base-uri]` to automatically open in your default browser (although not incognito).

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of that command in drush. That helped me pinpoint the problem (it was related to a specific role check on the coupon).